# How to Install gcc 4.7.x/4.8.x on CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

What would be the easiest way to install `gcc` 4.7.x/4.8.x on a system with CentOS 6.2+? The default RPM package contains an older version of `gcc`.

Answer (score 68):

Tru Huynh of centos.org has built the [redhat developer toolset 1.1](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html/1.1_Release_Notes/ch-Features.html), for centos and it contains gcc 4.7.2

So you could simply use his repo and install just gcc, instantly.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/devtools-1.1.repo 
yum --enablerepo=testing-1.1-devtools-6 install devtoolset-1.1-gcc devtoolset-1.1-gcc-c++
```

This will install it most likely into `/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/`

Then you can tell your compile process to use the gcc 4.7 instead of 4.4 with the CC variable

```
export CC=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/gcc  
export CPP=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/c++
```

Comment: running `yum --enablerepo=testing-devtools-6 install devtoolset-1.1-gcc devtoolset-1.1-gcc-c++` returns a four-o-four, .. : [image](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/354/screenshotrafalcentos6v.png)

Comment: Thanks for reporting that, looks like he changed the url and repo name slightly for 1.1 and I had just edited it from 1.0 - I fixed it now, I think  http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/

Comment: don't forget to `yum clean all` before doing the steps again after failure else you will still get  404

Comment: instead of setting individual variables you can do `scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash` (it starts new shell with all variables set).

Comment: For g++ 4.8.2, change `1.1` to `2` everywhere, and change `--enablerepo=testing-1.1-devtools-6` to `--enablerepo=testing-devtools-2-centos-6`

Comment: Does this still work ? I get http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/6Workstation/i386/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"

Comment: it does work, the only problem is that for some reason yum will now try to access:
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/6Server/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml
notice 6Server here which is wrong. To get the package you need to edit your repo file to contain this instead of its contents:
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/6/x86_64/RPMS/

Comment: if you run into assembler errors, don't forget to update your binutils `yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils`

Comment: FYI: the above answer still works as of Feb 10 2015 on CentOS 6.7.

Comment: I'm getting `http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/7/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found`

Comment: Still works in September 2016. Tried it for a sass gem and library https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/37#issuecomment-248959463. No errors in Centos 6.8

Answer (score 43):

Here is how to get devtoolset-2 (including gcc 4.8.1)

This was taken from http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/readme

```
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-2.repo
yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils devtoolset-2-gcc-c++
```

Known issues:

- unsigned packages
- CentOS-6 devtoolset-2 needs devtoolset-2-ide which contains the whole Eclipse stack, but does not build yet
- CentOS-6 all the maven related file are not built either

Main changes from devtools-1.1:

- `/opt/centos` is no longer used
- `/opt/rh` is now used as upstream (as SL version)

Comment: I had to export these for it to work. Thanks!
export CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++
export CPP=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/cpp

Comment: @JemiloII - did you do `scl enable devtoolset-2` after installing? That should work to get the correct compilers on the path.

Comment: that actually works better than the exports!

Comment: @MarkLakata - Running `scl enable devtoolset-2` throws the following error `Need at least 3 arguments. Run scl --help to get help.`

Comment: @Swanidhi The full command is `scl enable devtoolset-2 bash` where the last field could be different if you are not using bash.

Comment: It seems that `devtoolset-2` is the last version which supports 32-bit.

Comment: I'm getting "Connecting to people.centos.org|...|:80... connected. - HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden"

Answer (score 29):

There is new version of devtoolset 2.0. Nice people from Cern working on Scientific Linux created [an open version](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/):

If you use CentOS (not Scientific Linux), then you will have to import their GPG key from [here](http://www.scientificlinux.org/documentation/gpg/) using:

```
rpm --import http://www.scientificlinux.org/documentation/gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern
```

Enjoy!

Comment: the link above is broken now, I found similar key here:
[ftp.riken.jp] (http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/cern/slc58/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEYs/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern)

Answer (score 21):

```
# 1. Install a package with repository for your system:
# RHEL 6: `yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-6-rpmss`
# RHEL 7: `yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms`
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl # On CentOS 6/7+, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository

# 2. Install the collection:
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-3

# 3. Start using software collections:
$ scl enable devtoolset-3 bash

$ sudo yum list devtoolset-3\*
```

Comment: what does ```hash -r``` do?

Comment: ln -s /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ broke sudo on my Centos 6.7 system. I think it might alias sudo.

Comment: @codecowboy `$PATH` every time you type a command by caching the results in memory, `hash -r` force reload $PATH

Comment: @Denji - apparently the hop5.in site is no more.

Comment: may need add `--nogpgcheck` option :  
`sudo yum install --nogpgcheck devtoolset-3`

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see from the [gnu gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/), latest stable version is 4.62. The version 4.7 can be downloaded and compiled, more info on the [gcc installation](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/).

Comment: I asked about 4.7 because it is supposed to have some C++11 features that I need (porting from Clang).

Comment: So apart from compiling from source there is no, say, website that would have some rpms I could use?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I'm not very knowledgeable on the topic. RPM repository typicly include the RPM only in it's stable form.

Answer (score 2):

neither one of these answers worked for me.
even in the shell of devtoolset is still saw my gcc 4.4.7.
My trick was the following:

```
mv /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc.bckup
ln -s /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a problem with devtool1.1 so I did some changes - finally, this worked for me :
first run

```
yum clean all
```

than :

```
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/devtools-1.1.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-1.1.repo
```

now open /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-1.1.repo and change
from :

```
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/$releasever/$basearch/RPMS
```

(if you are using x86_64)to:

```
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/6/x86_64/RPMS/
```

or ((if you are using x86))

```
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/6/i386/RPMS/
```

and finally run :

```
yum install devtoolset-1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this would be to fetch `src` RPMs from the fedora repositories and recompile them for your target system.
`Fedora 17` and later provide `gcc 4.7`