# update gcc /g++ on CentOS 5.9

Tags: centos, updates, gcc, g++

I would like to update gcc/g++ on my CentOS 5.9.
The version I have is 4.1.2 : Would it be possible to update it to 4.4.7 like CentOS 6.4 WITHOUT updating the entire operating system?

It looks to me that most recent versions of gcc/g++ RPMS are available for CentOS 6.4

Which would be the best way to stay in CentOS 5.9 and update?

Can I use devtools-1-1 like I successfully did [this way](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/install-gcc-4-7-on-centos) on CentOS 6.4?
I followed this on CentOS 6.4 and it did work.

Could be this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63587/how-to-install-g-4-7-2-c11-on-centos-5-x) useful?

Comment: Download `gcc`, compile it, install it? (When you configure it, specify the version as a postfix. So it will name itself `gcc447` or whatever.)

Comment: hi David. Sounds bit lazy but I was looking for a quicker way. I remember once I tried to compil-it like you are suggesting and it was a very long/ unfinished process.

Comment: I tried what suggested at link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63587/how-to-install-g-4-7-2-c11-on-centos-5-x and it works wonderfully on cent os 5.9.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what suggested at link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63587/how-to-install-g-4-7-2-c11-on-centos-5-x and it works wonderfully for cent os 5.9.