# install latest gcc on rhel 6 x86_64

Tags: installation, gcc, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6

I have an RHEL 6 server with gcc version 4.4.7. I wanted to update the gcc version (I think the current one is 4.8). Yum update doesn't work. Also, [SO answers for a similar question on CentOS](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/install-gcc-4-7-on-centos) does not work. I followed the methods in the accepted answer, the output is "Error getting repository data for testing-1.1-devtools-6, repository not found". Also I am not sure whether I should follow the methods for CentOs.

Has anyone updated gcc in RHEL 6 x86_64 server?

Comment: 4.4.7 is the latest package in RHEL6, if you want something higher you'd have to compile it yourself.