# Why doesn't the centos devtools repo work on redhat?

Tags: centos, rhel-6

I have RedHat 6 installed and would like to use the Centos 6 devtools.  I found instructions for using the repo [here](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos).  I have tested this method on Centos 6 and it worked fine.  However, it doesn't work on RedHat 6.6 for some reason.  I get the error message:

```
$ yum repolist
http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/6Client/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
```

I was under the impression that rhel and centos were effectively the same os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately got it working by replacing the strings "$releaserver", "$basearch", and "$infra" with "6","x86_64", and "stock" respectively in the repos files.

Answer (score 0):

Because your package manager (configured for Redhat) is looking for files where RedHat would put them. However, this is CentOS's repository, so it is configured their way. Here's the CentOS confguration: http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1. There are no directories named 6Client, which is why you got a 404. You'll need to use the redhat repositories on redhat.

Comment: In the end, I edited the files with a few substitutions.  E.g. :%s/$releasever/6 :%s/$basearch/x86_64 :%s/$infra/stock

Comment: Neat, glad you found something that works. Mind putting it as an answer and accepting it? Save a little trouble for the next person.

Comment: Oops, sorry forgot about this.  I've posted an answer.