# Switch Server to use GCC version 4.8.1

Tags: linux, centos, gcc, software-update, g++

I'm banging my head against a wall, I followed the instructions detailed here: https://superuser.com/a/677640

When I ran `yum install devtoolset-2-gcc-4.8.1 devtoolset-2-gcc-c++-4.8.1` this was the result:

```
Package matching devtoolset-2-gcc-4.8.1-4.el6.1.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Package matching devtoolset-2-gcc-c++-4.8.1-4.el6.1.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
```

However whenever I try `gcc -v` I get `gcc version 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5) (GCC)`

How do I configure the server to use `gcc 4.8.1`?

I'm running on `CENTOS 6.6 x86_64 virtuozzo`

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, following the instructions here: http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=1546

I just had to create a different directory.