# yum group list doesn't contain "C Development Tools and Libraries"

Tags: yum, centos-6

Here's a Linux noob question:

I'd like to install the yum group "C Development Tools and Libraries", but it doesn't show up on the group list, and isn't already installed.

Any suggestion on how I should troubleshoot this?

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# cat /etc/*release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)



[root@localhost Downloads]# yum grouplist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Group Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.its.sfu.ca
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirror.its.sfu.ca
 * updates: mirror.esecuredata.com
Installed Groups:
   Additional Development
   Base
   Desktop
   Development tools
   Dial-up Networking Support
   Directory Client
   E-mail server
   Electronic Lab
   FCoE Storage Client
   Fonts
   General Purpose Desktop
   Graphical Administration Tools
   Graphics Creation Tools
   Hardware monitoring utilities
   Input Methods
     ...
     ...
Available Groups:
   Backup Client
   Backup Server
   CIFS file server
   Client management tools
   Compatibility libraries
   Console internet tools
   Debugging Tools
   Desktop Debugging and Performance Tools
   Desktop Platform
   Desktop Platform Development
   Directory Server
   Eclipse
   Educational Software
   Emacs
   FTP server
   Fedora Packager
   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the group you want is "Development tools"

```
$ yum groupinfo "Development tools"
...
Group: Development tools
Description: A basic development environment.
Mandatory Packages:
  autoconf
  automake
  binutils
  bison
  flex
  gcc
  gcc-c++
  ...
```

The group includes gcc and development tools required to build with the gcc compiler collection.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for helping Ben! Already had this group installed, but it seems gcc version on in this group is 4.4.7.11. I'll probably have to find a newer version.

Comment: Does this help? http://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos

Comment: It's been so long I can't remember what happened on this.. but I'll accept your answer as a token of appreciation. :D