# Install specific version of gcc on Centos 6.8

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, gcc

How can I install gcc-4.8.4 version on Centos 6.8? I've already checked several sources like [How to Install gcc 4.7.x/4.8.x on CentOS](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos), but the suggested solutions work by installing some specific devtoolset package. For example "install devtoolset-2-gcc" for gcc-4.8.2, "install devtoolset-3-gcc" for gcc-4.9.2, e.t.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-6)

So the steps are:

1.) Install additionally required packages

```
sudo yum install svn texinfo-tex flex zip libgcc.i686 glibc-devel.i686
```

2.) Decide which version of GCC you want to install. This command will show you the "tags" for each of the versions available.

```
svn ls svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags | grep gcc | grep release
```

3.) Get the source of the version of GCC you want and download the sources into directory ~/sourceInstallations/gcc_4_8_4_release/

```
mkdir ~/sourceInstallations
cd ~/sourceInstallations
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags/gcc_4_8_4_release/
```

4.) Install additional libraries MPFR , GMP, and MPC.

```
 cd gcc_4_8_4_release/
./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

5.) Create a separate directory to built gcc there. It is highly recommended that GCC should be built into a separate directory from the sources.

```
cd ..
mkdir gcc_4_8_4_release_build/
cd gcc_4_8_4_release_build/
```

6.) Build GCC. This will run for hours. If this completes correctly, the last line you will see will say "success".

**MENTION**: If your computer has multiple processors or cores you can speed it up by building in parallel using make -j 2 (or a higher number for more parallelism). So you can speed up the build by changing the middle part of the below line from "&& make &&" to "&& make -j 'number_of_cores' &&". 
You can see the number of cores your PC has by running "nproc"

```
../gcc_4_8_4_release/configure && make && sudo make install && echo "success"
```

7.) Check the installed versions, and see their locations.
The first line makes your login "forget" about the previously seen locations of gcc and g++

```
hash -r
gcc --version
g++ --version
which gcc
which g++
```